# Android: Выпадение Spinner'а

Tags: android, java, android-spinner

Столкнулся с проблемой:

Есть Spinner. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на него выпадал список (плавненько так вниз).
Вместо этого при нажатии на Spinner список не выпадает, а открывается в диалоге.

Как реализовать выпадение списка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работает в AppCompat

```
import android.widget.Spinner;

Spinner r1;
String[] spinner_values = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // spinner_layout - мой стиль для спиннеров (размер текста, gravity по центру)
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_layout, spinner_values)
    {
        // Текст в спиннерах будет расположен по центру
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
               ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
               return v;
        }
    };

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    r1 = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.r1); r1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Spinner android:spinnerMode="dropdown" .... />

//вместо "dialog" написать "dropdown"
```

Comment: Хм...Это гениально. Но вот требует API +11... Как это реализовать в AppCompat?